# Converting enhanced loop into Java 8 Streams, filter - forEach

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to learn Java 8. Is there a way to turn the method below into Java 8 Streams, `filter`, and `forEach`. If so, how?

```
protected void isValidId(CarModel model, List<String> errors) throws DataAccessException {

    CarStyle[] styles = model.getStyles();

    for(CarStyle style : styles){
        if(!style.isModels()){
            if(style.getStyleId() > 99){
          errors.add(INVALID_ID + ", Id:" + style.getStyleId());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I read some tutorials on java 8 but unsure how to implement this. Thanks.

**EDIT:** I added a list to the method.

Comment: It would help if you described what the loop is supposed to do - right now it doesn't return anything or do anything with the data, so it's hard to answer

Comment: Is that the whole code? What is inside the if? Don't tell me there is nothing, and the methods called inside the `if`s have side-effects! Why does a method named isXxx return void instead of a boolean, as expected?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Transforming following code to Java Stream API is pretty easy when you read stream documentation. Pasting a final result wont help you learning Java 8 unfortunately.

Comment: please see edit. I added a list to the method

Comment: After your edit the code makes less sense than before. If you are trying to add elements to an list to use from the calling function, don't add it as an argument but make it the return type. Otherwise I see no point in adding the list as an argument, rather use a local variable to use in the function

Comment: Is there any reason why you are passing the error list as an argument? Why not just create it there and return?

Comment: I am adding a method to a code base that already exists. I am following the construct of all the other methods in this class. I cannot change this.

Comment: @piddler fair enough. My answer should be exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your nested `if` statements are equal to `filter`. Later on, you can convert your filtered elements to error strings and collect them to an existing collection:

```
Arrays.stream(model.getStyles())
  .filter(s -> !s.isModels() && s.getStyleId() > 99)
  .map(s -> String.format("%s, Id:%d", INVALID_ID, s.getStyleId()))
  .forEach(errors::add);
```

or...the more reasonable option would be to return a list of errors and not `void`:

```
return Arrays.stream(model.getStyles())
  .filter(s -> !s.isModels() && s.getStyleId() > 99)
  .map(s -> String.format("%s, Id:%d", INVALID_ID, s.getStyleId()))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: *[collectionFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection-java.util.function.Supplier-) - a Supplier which returns a **new, empty** Collection of the appropriate type*

Comment: @piddler both options work - this option is slightly better

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the method calls don't have side effects, you don't think about editing the array inside the for loop (which doesn't work with the approach in your question either), you could rewrite your code like this:

```
protected void isValidId(CarModel model)
{
    CarStyle styles[] = model.getStyles();

    Arrays.stream(styles)
          .filter(style -> !style.isModels() && style.getStyleId() > 99)
          .forEach(style -> {

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the result of your code should be so I'm assuming that you want to only filter those `CarStyle`s which match condition.

you could write something like this:

```
    CarStyle[] styles = model.getStyles();
    return Stream.of(styles)
          .filter(style -> !style.isModels() && style.getStyleId() > 99)
          .map(style -> INVALID_ID.concat(", Id:").concat(style.getStyleId()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: the duplicate filter will make the code less efficient

Comment: @msrd0 not enough to care about it

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek Depends on the size of the array, but probably you are right

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void isValidId(CarModel model) throws DataAccessException {

    CarStyle[] styles = model.getStyles();
    Stream<CarStyle> stylesStream = Arrays.stream(styles);

    stylesStream.filter(style -> !style.isModels())
        .filter(style.getStyleId() > 99)
        .forEach(System.out::println)        
}
```

The above code snippet will print out all styles which meet the requirements.

---

**EDIT**

```
protected void isValidId(CarModel model, List<String> errors) throws DataAccessException {

    CarStyle[] styles = model.getStyles();
    Stream<CarStyle> stylesStream = Arrays.stream(styles);

    stylesStream.filter(style -> !style.isModels())
        .filter(style -> style.getStyleId() > 99)
        .forEach( s-> errors.add(INVALID_ID + ", Id:" + s.getStyleId())  
}
```

This code snippet will do the same as your code.

I recommend you this tutorial:
http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/

Comment: Cant we shorten it to Arrays.stream(model.getStyles).filter(ect)?

Comment: @piddler Yes, we can.